# How can I reuse a piece of HTML as a component and pass it to multiple components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to ask for a way to create a component, and from that Component, I can use it as a child component for multiple other Components to use.

In my case:

I have set up a route like this in `App.js`, it's very simple

```
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Newest />} />
            <Route path="/movies" element={<Movies />} />
            <Route path="/tv" element={<TvShows />} />
            <Route path="/series" element={<Series />} />
            <Route path="/cartoons" element={<Cartoons />} />
        </Routes>
```

From then , I create 5 other components: `Newest`, `Movies`, `TvShows`, `Series`, `Cartoon`

As I see from my code, there's a piece of JSX that I've always used, for example

This is my `Newest` component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { SITE_API } from "../../constants/constants"

function Newest() {
    const [newestData, setNewestData] = useState([])
    const newestUrl = `${SITE_API}/update-film`

    useEffect(() => {
        const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
        const source = CancelToken.source()

        axios
            .get(newestUrl, { cancelToken: source.token })
            .then((data) => {
                setNewestData(data.data.data.items)
            })
            .catch((thrown) => {
                if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) return
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <h2>NEWEST</h2>
            <div className="holder-item">
                {newestData.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="item" key={i}>
                            <img
                                src={`shorten-URL-that-I-use{item.thumb_url}`}
                                alt=""
                            />
                            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Newest
```

There's a whole `"holder-item"` section that I can reuse for 4 Components left.

I tried to create a component called `ItemCard` and paste that whole section inside of it, it's like this:

```
import React from "react"

function ItemCard({ newestData }) {
    console.log(newestData)

    return (
        <>
            {newestData.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                    <div className="item" key={i}>
                        <img
                            src={`shorten-URL-that-I-use${item.thumb_url}`}
                            alt=""
                        />
                        <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}

export default ItemCard
```

And from that, back to `Newest` component, I changed it to:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { SITE_API } from "../../constants/constants"

import ItemCard from "../ItemCard"

function Newest() {
    const [newestData, setNewestData] = useState([])
    const newestUrl = `${SITE_API}/update-film`

    useEffect(() => {
        const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
        const source = CancelToken.source()

        axios
            .get(newestUrl, { cancelToken: source.token })
            .then((data) => {
                setNewestData(data.data.data.items)
            })
            .catch((thrown) => {
                if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) return
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <h2>NEWEST</h2>
            <div className="holder-item">
                <ItemCard newestData={newestData} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Newest
```

So, is there a way for me to use the `ItemCard` component for 4 other components left? Because I think I need to pass 4 other props to `ItemCard`, but if so, how can I use it for each route, it's my first time trying this method, so please instruct me, I don't know what's this situation call to google it myself, thanks.

Comment: I think it already is going to work. Am I wrong? Just place `ItemCard` in other pages. I only suggest changing the prop name to something else that would make more sense like `<ItemCard items={newestData} />` and catching that `items` prop inside the component.

Comment: That makes sense, I feel bugged in my head wondering if it feels a bit wrong, guess changing `newestData={newestData}` to `items={newestData}` makes everything clear, thanks. Before I thought that I need to pass 4 other props down to `ItemCard`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like you've already used it here, but you will either have to pass "newestData" as a prop, assuming it has a children/parent relationship. If it doesn't, you can use a common library called redux, with which you can set a global state of the newestData and use it anywhere in your code. If you do not want to use another library, you can accomplish the same using the built in react hook useContext.